# Database with a native versioned document type?

Tags: database, versioning, documents

I know there are patterns for building versioning and audit trails on top of various data stores. I'm curious: Is there a DBMS (SQL or otherwise) with a *native* type for storing versioned textual documents? I'm not talking about a VCS like git  that stores versions that apply across a whole repo.  I'm talking about version histories for individual records.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB has this, as it is needed for its optimistic locking, append only and replication. However it is not intended to be used for long term versioning: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/DocumentRevisions

Even Oracle can do that with point in time queries on CLOBs.